# Set up Jaeger with OpenTelemetry

Tags: telemetry, jaeger, distributed-tracing

I have built a sample app to understand the trace and span using OpenTelemetry. I want to see them in Jaeger UI. How to set up Jaeger with my application which uses OpenTelemetry for tracing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start a jaeger container:

```sh
docker run --rm --name jaeger -d -p 16686:16686 -p 6831:6831/udp jaegertracing/all-in-one
```

Then you should by able to access to the Jaeger UI at http://localhost:16686

Once you've have a Jaeger up and running, you need to configure a Jaeger exporter to forward spans to Jaeger. This will depends of the language used.

[Here](https://opentelemetry-python.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting-started.html#configure-exporters-to-emit-spans-elsewhere) is the straightforward documentation to do so in python.